# DirectX setup Internal Error when installing Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3, directx

When trying to install Mass Effect 3 on my Windows 7 machine I got the following message at 99% installed:

[image: Mass Effect 3 DirectX Setup Error]

I have made sure that i have the most resent version of DirectX form [the web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=35).

I found this video when searching for a solution

But I don't see a DirectX folder in the Mass Effect 3 folder.

Comment: This is also the case for Mass Effect 1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3\ __Installer\directx\redist
2. Delete all the contents of the folder except for the following files:
   DSETUP.dll
   dsetup32.dll
   DXSETUP.exe
3. Install Mass Effect 3 again.

Note change the Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games prefix if you installed to a custom location.

Comment: This was my problem. The DirectX folder was already inside the __Installer folder

Comment: This fix works for Command & Conquer Generals too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running DxDiag?  See if you can get any additional information from there.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Run-DirectX-Diagnostic-Tool

> DirectX Diagnostic Tool helps you troubleshoot issues with the DirectX suite of multimedia technologies that come with Windows. If you're having trouble getting game animation or a movie to run properly, you should run DirectX Diagnostic Tool to try to find the source of the problem.
>
> To run DirectX Diagnostic Tool:
>
> Open DirectX Diagnostic Tool by clicking the Start button, typing dxdiag in the Search box, and then pressing ENTER.

Note: I know this would be better as a comment, but I don't have comment everywhere yet.  Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your computer after install, worked for me when it did not work until I rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by granting admin permissions for all users on the origin folder, then installing DirectX 9, and only then installing the game.

Comment: Most people use non-administrator user profile, so granting Administrator permissions, seems overkill

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, and used what tiddy said. Deleted the files except those three and then the game started updating. Its all good.

Some more problems and solutions for ME3 installation are also here (including the answer above)
http://segmentnext.com/2012/02/26/mass-effect-3-errors-crashes-freezes-frame-rate-fix-origin-and-fixes/

credits to the ones who made them